# Layout troubles

Tags: android, layout

I am having a spot of bother with a fairly simple layout. Here it is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"/>

  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

3 Questions:

- How do I center vertical both TextViews (or perhaps better said, the text within those views) within the parent LinearLayout? The left view is vertically centered OK, but the right one (because it has a smaller font) is not. It seems to be centered vertically at the top. I obviously tried playing with layout_gravity of the second view but that makes no difference whatsoever. The only way I can solve it is to wrap the second TextView in a LinearLayout with its layout height parameter set to match_parent (but is this the correct way of doing this?)
- Similarly, I want the View on the left horizontally centered on the left, and the View on the right horizontally centered on the right. Currently the right View is placed immediatly next to the left one. The only way I can solve this is by adding something like this inbetween the two text views:

  ```
  <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="">
  ```

  basically acting as a spacer which decreases in size depending on the legth of the text in both TextViews
- I want the text in the left View to be truncated if the combined text of the Views does not fit horizontally. No wrapping onto a new line. Currently the text in the left View simply "pushes" the right one out of the parent. No idea how to achieve that (apart from adding `android:maxLines="1"` to stop the text from wrapping). I have tried `android:ellipsize="end"` but that does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: set android:gravity="center_vertical" in linear layout.

Comment: Thank you. That answers the first part!

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use Relative layout , but still if you want to do the same thing in Linear layout than do some changes in your xml file
-First is set Linear layout hight as match parent :

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizonatal">
```

-Second for making the views visible at centre vertical do

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

same property android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal" , you have to add in second text view also.

It will make your both text view appear at centre vertical but one next to other.
To make the second view appear on right I think you can add
 android:layout_marginLeft="xx dp"
put some value in place of xx.

For your third question about truncating your text, you should give some size to your TextView not wrap content..Like `android:layout_width ="25dp"`
and then use `android:ellipsize="end"`.

I guess you will get that..Actually I am in hurry,time to leave the office.